# Mailto link send onclick without user input

Tags: javascript, email, automation

We use mailto links within email notifications to allow users to confirm or deny that a ticket has been completed. These have specific subjects and bodies that are dynamically generated for the ticket already, the user does not have to do anything to the new email except hit send. The email is received by our ticketing system and either closes or reopens a ticket based on which mailto was pressed.

Is there any way to immediately send the email when the user clicks the mailto link? Our company uses outlook as the mail client.

Comment: No, that's not how `mailto:` works. Why don't you use links that open a web page instead of `mailto:` links?

Comment: Think about it, if you could do this, you could make the user send spam mails to anyone without them knowing what they were sending. Serious security violation.